# Why does bash post-increment operator set a nonzero result code?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

This caught me by surprise: applying the post-increment operator
(`++`) to a zero value variable results in a non-zero result code.
That is, given:

```
#!/bin/bash
myvar=0
let myvar++
echo "result: $?"
```

Running that (with bash 5.1.0) results in:

```
result: 1
```

Why does that produce a nonzero result code?  We see the same behavior
using a numeric expression:

```
#!/bin/bash
myvar=0
(( myvar++ ))
echo "result: $?"
```

On the other hand, if we use `+=` instead of `++`, or if we start with
a nonzero value of `myvar`, we receive a 0 result code as expected. The
following...

```
myvar=1
let myvar+=1
echo "result: $?"

myvar=1
let myvar++
echo "result: $?"

myvar=1
(( myvar++ ))
echo "result: $?"
```

...all produce:

```
result: 0
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `bash` man page, in the section describing `let`:

> Each  arg is an arithmetic expression to be evaluated (see ARITHMETIC EVALUATION).  If the last arg evaluates to 0, let returns 1; 0 is returned otherwise

It's not the operator that establishes the value of `$?`, it is `let`.  Since the value of the argument to `let` in the command `let myvar++` is 0, `let` returns 1.

Comment: Spot on with the documentation; thanks! That sentence remains unclear to me. In `myvar=0; let myvar++`, I would say that the last arg evaluates to `1`. I would expect `$? == 1` after, say, `myvar=1; let myvar--`.

Comment: The operator is called **post**increment, not **pre**increment. You get as a result the value **before** incrementation. Hence, `x=1; echo $((1 + x++))` returns 2, not 3.

Comment: If `myvar` is set to 0, then @larsks `myvar++` evaluates to 0, while `++myvar` evaluates to 1.  Both change `myvar` so that its new value is 1.

Answer (score 1):

For post-increment expressions, bash evaluates the variable and sets the result code *before* applying the increment. In each case where the value before the post-increment was 0, it follows the documented behavior,

> If the last arg evaluates to 0, let returns 1; 0 is returned otherwise.

Note the difference if you use pre-increment,

```
myvar=0
let ++myvar
echo "result: $?"

>> result: 0
```

In `exp0()` in https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/expr.c#n1014 , for PREINC it binds the (stringifed) value of `v2` then assigns it to `val`, but under POSTINC it binds the variable then discards `v2` without assigning it to `val`.